# получить подписчиков группы больше 1000

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Речь идет о методе [groups.getMembers](https://new.vk.com/dev/groups.getMembers)
В респонсе есть ограничение в 1000 пользователей, т.е если вы хотите получить больше этого количества (паблик миллионник), то это не получится.

Работаю через библиотеку vklancer, вот фрагмент кода (на всякий случай):

```
array = api.groups.getMembers(group_id=*****)["response"]["items"]
for i in array:
    ... #тут я что-то делаю с данными пользователей
... #тут сохраняю в DB
```

смотрю количество столбцов - ровно 1000, в паблике 1400 человек.

Каким образом забрать всех пользователей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте параметр offset

```
array = api.groups.getMembers(group_id=1, offset=1000)["response"]["items"]
```

Таким образом вы получите тысячу участников, начиная с тысячного.

Я не знаю питона, но что бы получить всех участников группы можно использовать примерно следующий код:

```
offset = 0
count = 0
array = []

while True: 
    resp = api.groups.getMembers(group_id=9713780, offset=offset)["response"]
    array += resp["items"]
    offset += 1000
    if offset > resp["count"] :
        break

for i in array:
    print(i)
```